# Tailwind grid is uneven for one element

Tags: html, css, next.js, tailwind-css, css-grid

I'm working on a portfolio website using NextJS and TailwindCSS on this [Github Page](https://github.com/VanshSharma14/resume-website) and on the last page (projects) I'm using cards to display each project.

The cards use this as a template

```
<div class="max-w-sm bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-lg shadow dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
    <a href="#">
        <img class="rounded-t-lg" src="/docs/images/blog/image-1.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
    <div class="p-5">
        <a href="#">
            <h5 class="mb-2 text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Noteworthy technology acquisitions 2021</h5>
        </a>
        <p class="mb-3 font-normal text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">Here are the biggest enterprise technology acquisitions of 2021 so far, in reverse chronological order.</p>
        <a href="#" class="inline-flex items-center px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-center text-white bg-blue-700 rounded-lg hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800">
            Read more
             <svg class="w-3.5 h-3.5 ml-2" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 14 10">
                <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M1 5h12m0 0L9 1m4 4L9 9"/>
            </svg>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[And the result looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUc1d.png)

I can't figure out why that one card is disproportionate. I even tried copying one of the other cards and changing values, but this seems to be an issue for just the first card. Something similar happens if the cards are stacked vertically.

[The result of resizing the window so the cards stack vertically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP19Q.png)

You can use my repo to reproduce the issue. Also, keep in mind this is a learning frontend project for me so the code is kind of all over the place.

Comment: It looks like your problem is not the card component but the wrapper of the cards, my guess is that you have something like `space-x-6` causing the shift for posts after the first on mobile, and `space-y-6` causing the shift on larger screens.

Impossible to tell from what you've shared here, also your Github project does not have a page called projects from the looks of it, maybe you need to push that.

Comment: @JHeth By the projects page I meant `index.js` because I have my website laid out as 3 different pages merged into 1 big scroller page.  And yes you were right, I forgot to push the changes. Additionally, I am using space-x-6 but I don't see why that would make only one element disproportional.

Comment: the issue is that you're using `space-x-6 space-y-6` this causes space to be injected via margins on child elements. You don't want a space-y utility affecting horizontal rows. A better solution is to simply use `grid` utilities, you can manage space between items with the `gap` utility.

Comment: Wow that fixed it. Thanks so much! I'm so new to this stuff so this is a big lesson for me, so thanks for that too.